# Angular 2 http promise doesnt map the object correctly

Tags: angular2-services

I am using angular 2 to show data from a Restfull service.

When I do the api call with my service, it is possible to see the json-output of fitbits API. But when I want to map the data to an angular2 class, something goes wrong and i can't see the data.

```js
constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getHeartrates (): Promise<HeartRate> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1TE1ENkMiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjg5OUciLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJyc29jIHJzZXQgcmFjdCBybG9jIHJ3ZWkgcmhyIHJudXQgcnBybyByc2xlIiwiZXhwIjoxNDkyNTIxMTQ0LCJpYXQiOjE0OTE5MTYzNDR9.aP44gsdkQXmlRlkN65cEVKXNmqMWZXECOMzP0tDJzng' });
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(this.heartrateUrl, options)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    // let newbody = JSON.parse(body);
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Promise.reject(errMsg);
  }
```

```css
    export class HeartRate {
        activities_heart: ActivitiesHeart[];
        activities_heart_intraday: ActivitiesHeartIntraday;
    }
    
    class HeartRateZone {
        caloriesOut: number;
        max: number;
        min: number;
        minutes: number;
        name: string;
    }

    class ActivitiesHeart {
        customHeartRateZones: any[];
        dateTime: string;
        heartRateZones: HeartRateZone[];
        value: string;
    }

    class Dataset {
        time: string;
        value: number;
    }

    class ActivitiesHeartIntraday {
        dataset: Dataset[];
        datasetInterval: number;
        datasetType: string;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Show something about heartrates</h2>
<p>{{ heartratelist?.activities_heart_intraday?.dataset[0]?.value }}</p>
<ul *ngFor="#item of heartratelist?.activities_heart_intraday?.dataset">
    <li>{{item.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

This is what the json returns

```js
{
 "activities-heart": [{
  "customHeartRateZones": [],
  "dateTime": "today",
  "heartRateZones": [{
   "caloriesOut": 26.01129,
   "max": 97,
   "min": 30,
   "minutes": 14,
   "name": "Out of Range"
  }, {
   "caloriesOut": 0,
   "max": 135,
   "min": 97,
   "minutes": 0,
   "name": "Fat Burn"
  }, {
   "caloriesOut": 0,
   "max": 164,
   "min": 135,
   "minutes": 0,
   "name": "Cardio"
  }, {
   "caloriesOut": 0,
   "max": 220,
   "min": 164,
   "minutes": 0,
   "name": "Peak"
  }],
  "value": "58.62"
 }],
 "activities-heart-intraday": {
  "dataset": [{
   "time": "10:13:46",
   "value": 65
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:13",
   "value": 70
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:28",
   "value": 70
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:33",
   "value": 80
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:38",
   "value": 79
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:43",
   "value": 76
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:48",
   "value": 73
  }, {
   "time": "10:21:53",
   "value": 73
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:03",
   "value": 67
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:08",
   "value": 63
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:13",
   "value": 59
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:23",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:33",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:43",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:22:53",
   "value": 62
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:03",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:08",
   "value": 62
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:13",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:18",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:23",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:28",
   "value": 59
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:33",
   "value": 59
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:43",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:23:58",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:13",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:23",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:28",
   "value": 59
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:33",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:48",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:53",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:24:58",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:25:13",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:25:28",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:25:33",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:25:48",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:25:58",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:26:08",
   "value": 57
  }, {
   "time": "10:26:18",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:26:28",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:26:43",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:26:58",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:27:13",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:27:18",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:27:28",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:27:43",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:27:58",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:28:03",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:28:18",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:28:33",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:28:48",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:03",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:08",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:13",
   "value": 53
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:18",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:23",
   "value": 57
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:38",
   "value": 57
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:43",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:29:53",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:30:08",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:30:13",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:30:28",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:30:43",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:30:58",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:31:13",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:31:18",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:31:33",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:31:48",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:03",
   "value": 54
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:13",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:28",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:33",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:38",
   "value": 55
  }, {
   "time": "10:32:53",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:33:08",
   "value": 56
  }, {
   "time": "10:33:13",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:33:23",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:33:33",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:33:48",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:34:03",
   "value": 61
  }, {
   "time": "10:34:08",
   "value": 60
  }, {
   "time": "10:34:23",
   "value": 60
  }],
  "datasetInterval": 1,
  "datasetType": "second"
 }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
export class HeartRate {
    activities_heart: ActivitiesHeart[];
    activities_heart_intraday: ActivitiesHeartIntraday;
}
```

to

```
export class HeartRate {
    activities-heart: ActivitiesHeart[];
    activities-heart-intraday: ActivitiesHeartIntraday;
}
```

Changing the underscores to hyphens.

Though the problem with hyphens is that JavaScript treats `-` as an operator so you may have to access properties with `jsonObj['activities-heart']`.

Answer (score 0):

In your component subscribe your method

Eg:

```
constructor (private heartRateService: HeartRateService) {}

getHeartRate(){
   this.heartRateService.getHeartrates().subscribe(
      (info)=>{
         this.heartratelist=info;
      }
   );
}
```

Comment: `toPromise` doesn't require `subscribe`.